# Does the Single Sign On (SSO) Service Support Implicit Flow?

Tags: angularjs, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

We currently use the IBM Bluemix Single Sign On service with our hosted NodeJS application and it is working well. We now want to use that same SSO with a Single Page Application (SPA) built in AngularJS.

When I use either `oauth-ng` or `afOAuth2` they want to use the `response_type=token_id` for an implicit flow, but when I use that with Bluemix I get this error:

```
error=unsupported_response_type
error_description=CWOAU0027E: The response_type parameter was invalid: token_id
```

However when I set the `response_type=code` the SSO service redirects but none of the AngularJS packages know how to handle the response. I am guessing that is because they want to use the *implicit flow* and Bluemix wants to use the *authorization code flow*.

My question is can I use the Bluemix SSO service with a client that is not NodeJS/WLP running in Bluemix and does it support the Implicit Flow?

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix Single Sign Servivce is designed to only work with Node.JS and JAVA(Liberty) Applications.

If you wish to have it supported on other types of applications then you will need to open an Enhancement Request to do that please see the following link.

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/257231/how-can-i-submit-a-request-for-enhancement-rfe-for-1.html